# LensStudio script.remoteServiceModule is undefined

Tags: filter, snapchat

I have this script in a SnapChat filter

```
// @input Asset.RemoteServiceModule remoteServiceModule
var request = global.RemoteApiRequest.create();
request.endpoint = "start"
script.remoteServiceModule.performApiRequest(request, function(response){
if(response.statusCode !== 1){
print("Request Failed with code: " + String(response.statusCode))
return
}
})
```

but "script.remoteServiceModule" is undefined, so I can't make api request.
What can I do to fix this error? I working on Lens Studio 4.55.1
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add remote media module to your resources (for example import from the Api section of Asset Library) and set it as an input of this script!

[image]